# Autofac properties on request

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a service that depends on other services for example

```
OrderProvider(IOrderService service) {
}
```

That is a direct dependant so having it in the constructor is fine.
There are some other methods that require other services, so I have been handling these with **properties**, for example, I may need to get the **Stock** for an **Order**:

```
private IStockService _stockService;
public IStockService StockService { get { return _stockService ?? (_stockService = new StockService()); } }

Stock GetStock(string orderNumber) {
    return StockService.Get(orderNumber);
}
```

As you can see, in my old way of doing things the property was only instantiated when requested.
Now I have moved to autofac I would like to set up a similar method, i.e. If a request is only for an **Order** then only the **OrderProvider** and the **OrderService** will be instantiated, but if they request the **Stock** then all 3 will be instantiated.
I really hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofac allows you to request a `Lazy<T>` closed over the desired type for scenarios like yours that require delayed instantiation. The first time the `Lazy<T>`'s value is accessed is when the actual instance will be created.

#### Example Code

```
private Lazy<IStockService> _lazyStockService;

public IStockService StockService
{
    get { return _lazyStockService.Value; }
}

public OrderProvider( IOrderService service, Lazy<IStockService> lazyStockService )
{
    _service = service;
    _lazyStockService = lazyStockService;
}
```

[Here's a link to Autofac's docs on this topic](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#delayed-instantiation-lazy-b)

[Here's a link to the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Lazy<T>`